# showDialog won't show up

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application

I tried to create a managed user profile. I have been successful in retrieving the user info from the firestore. When I run the code using Pixel 3a emulator, the button that should have shown a dialogue box when the user presses to amend their data currently has no response when I try to modify the user profile. Flutter SDK 2.7.0 is what I'm using.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:jomasak/views/screens/auth/welcome_page.dart';
import 'package:jomasak/views/utils/AppColor.dart';
import 'package:jomasak/views/widgets/user_info_tile.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  String defaultImageURL =
      'https://pixabay.com/get/g066bc81cdaafbd755a118bbffa3223a1bd405dc2b5e972b603bf51a2bac5ad9c328e204c50642e1cb2b8c5574e9f5126aa31ca57206186d4ac7e15b8403ff8a61ae4a75edb280f4e1a9b572606dc6cf0_1280.png';
  String selectedFileName = '';
  XFile file;

  Future<void> editField(BuildContext context, String field) async {
    String newValue = "";
    TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Dialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Edit $field",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: textEditingController,
                  autofocus: true,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Enter new $field",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    newValue = value;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              ButtonBar(
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Cancel',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      newValue = textEditingController.text;
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(newValue);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Save',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    // Update the user's document in Firestore
    if (newValue.trim().isNotEmpty) {
      await userCollection.doc(currentUser.email).update({field: newValue});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        backgroundColor: AppColor.primary,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          'My Profile',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'inter',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              print("Signed Out");
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomePage()),
                (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
              );
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.logout,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 20,
            ),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.white,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(currentUser.email)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final userData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.data.data());
            return ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                // Section 1 - Profile Picture Wrapper
                Container(
                  color: AppColor.primary,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print('Code to open file manager');
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 130,
                          height: 130,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                            // Profile Picture
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/images/profile.jpeg'),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Change Profile Picture',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'inter',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 8),
                            SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/icons/camera.svg',
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // Section 2 - User Info Wrapper
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      UserInfoTile(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                        label: 'Email',
                        value: userData['email'],
                        onPressed: () => editField(context, 'email'),
                      ),
                      UserInfoTile(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                        label: 'Full Name',
                        value: userData['fullname'],
                        onPressed: () => editField(context, 'fullname'),
                      ),
                      UserInfoTile(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                        label: 'Username',
                        value: userData['username'],
                        onPressed: () => editField(context, 'username'),
                      ),
                      UserInfoTile(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                        label: 'Bio',
                        value: userData['bio'],
                        onPressed: () => editField(context, 'bio'),
                        valueBackground: AppColor.secondary,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Error ${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to edit user profile and update the details inside the firestore

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Em8.png)

I tried your code and the dialogue showed up. Maybe the problem is in **UserInfoTile** . Try checking that you are calling the **onPressed** function in UserInfoTile class.
If nothing works, then try restarting the app.

```
 flutter clean 
 flutter pub get
 flutter run
```

Comment: thanks, I managed to run the code and the dialogue showed up on the screen.